# How to draw a colored line in FASM with WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, assembly, graphics, gdi, fasm

I am currently trying to learn how to use FASM and I've been trying to make an application that draws colored lines using only WinAPI and GDI, but I can't figure out how to do that. I found this template for drawing lines, but they are always black.

```
format PE GUI 4.0

include 'win32wx.inc'

.data

_class TCHAR 'FASMWIN32',0
_title TCHAR 'Win32 program template',0
_error TCHAR 'Startup failed.',0

wc WNDCLASS 0,WindowProc,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,COLOR_BACKGROUND,NULL,_class

msg MSG

hdc dd ?
paintstruct PAINTSTRUCT

.code

start:
    invoke  GetModuleHandle,0
    mov [wc.hInstance],eax
    invoke  LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov [wc.hIcon],eax
    invoke  LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW
    mov [wc.hCursor],eax
    invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0xFFFFFF  
    mov [wc.hbrBackground], eax
    invoke  RegisterClass,wc
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error

    invoke  CreateWindowEx,0,_class,_title,WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,128,128,256,192,NULL,NULL,[wc.hInstance],NULL
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error
   
msg_loop:
    invoke  GetMessage,msg,NULL,0,0
    cmp eax,1
    jb  end_loop
    jne msg_loop
    invoke  TranslateMessage,msg
    invoke  DispatchMessage,msg
    jmp msg_loop

error:
    invoke  MessageBox,NULL,_error,NULL,MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK

end_loop:
    invoke  ExitProcess,[msg.wParam]

proc WindowProc uses ebx esi edi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam
    cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
    je  .wmdestroy
    cmp [wmsg], WM_PAINT
    je .wmpaint

.defwndproc:
    invoke  DefWindowProc,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    jmp .finish

.wmdestroy:
    invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
    xor eax,eax
    jmp .finish

.wmpaint:
    invoke BeginPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct 
    mov [hdc], eax  
    invoke MoveToEx, [hdc], 10, 15, 0  
    invoke LineTo, [hdc], 200, 100  
    invoke EndPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct  

.finish:
    ret
endp

.end start
```

This doesn't seem to work either, unless I am trying to put "hBrush HBRUSH" in the wrong place (doesn't work in '.data', 'illegal instruction'; "HBRUSH hBrush" doesn't work as well).

```
hBrush HBRUSH
invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0xFFFFFF
invoke SelectObject [hdc], hBrush
```

Can someone please give me an example of drawing colored lines with WinAPI and GDI?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto) is mandatory reading. You're going to have to read **all** of it.

Comment: Check out the return values out those winapi calls, see if GetLastError() returned any error after each WINAPI function call. Also, check if this code samples in C helps: http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/gdi/ translate it to fasm. I don't have fasm around right now to test your code

Comment: @Jack thanks a lot! My mistake was that I was trying to use brushes instead of pens to draw lines. If someone has the same question, the code is ```invoke CreatePen,PS_SOLID(or another pen style), 1, 0x000000(color) invoke SelectObject, [hdc], eax```

Comment: @fasm14 You can post an answer.

Comment: *"or another pen style"* - As explained in the documentation linked from the [very first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707815/how-to-draw-a-colored-line-in-fasm-with-winapi#comment116177295_65707815) you cannot use *"any"* pen style. It explicitly names geometric pens that will not use the pen color.

Comment: @fasm14 I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was that I was trying to use brushes instead of pens to draw lines. If someone has the same question, the code is:

```
    invoke CreatePen,PS_SOLID, 1, 0x000000 ; PS_SOLID is the pen style and 0x000000 is the color
    invoke SelectObject, [hdc], eax
    invoke MoveToEx, [hdc], 0, 32, 0
    invoke LineTo, [hdc], 256, 32
```

Full example:

```
format PE GUI 4.0

include 'win32wx.inc'

.data

_class TCHAR 'FASMWIN32',0
_title TCHAR 'Win32 program template',0
_error TCHAR 'Startup failed.',0

wc WNDCLASS 0,WindowProc,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,COLOR_BACKGROUND,NULL,_class

msg MSG

hdc dd ?
paintstruct PAINTSTRUCT

.code

start:
    invoke  GetModuleHandle,0
    mov [wc.hInstance],eax
    invoke  LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov [wc.hIcon],eax
    invoke  LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW
    mov [wc.hCursor],eax
    invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0xA0A0A0
    mov [wc.hbrBackground], eax
    invoke  RegisterClass,wc
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error
    invoke  CreateWindowEx,0,_class,_title,WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,128,128,256,192,NULL,NULL,[wc.hInstance],NULL
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error
msg_loop:
    invoke  GetMessage,msg,NULL,0,0
    cmp eax,1
    jb  end_loop
    jne msg_loop
    invoke  TranslateMessage,msg
    invoke  DispatchMessage,msg
    jmp msg_loop

error:
    invoke  MessageBox,NULL,_error,NULL,MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK

end_loop:
    invoke  ExitProcess,[msg.wParam]

proc WindowProc uses ebx esi edi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam
    cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
    je  .wmdestroy
    cmp [wmsg], WM_PAINT
    je .wmpaint

.defwndproc:
    invoke  DefWindowProc,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    jmp .finish

.wmdestroy:
    invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
    xor eax,eax
    jmp .finish

.wmpaint:
    invoke BeginPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct
    mov [hdc], eax
    invoke CreatePen,PS_SOLID, 1, 0x000000
    invoke SelectObject, [hdc], eax
    invoke MoveToEx, [hdc], 0, 32, 0
    invoke LineTo, [hdc], 256, 32
    invoke EndPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct  

.finish:
    ret
endp

.end start
```